# Google maps satellite view Pricing and limitations

Tags: google-maps, satellite

[This script](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example) at openstreetmap shows how one can use google's Satellite view as a layer on top of others.

I noticed that to do so, one does not need to supply any `API` key.

Does that mean that there are no limitation to the number of satellite views requests one can do?

In my case, I would like to use leaflet to display layers from both [mapbox](http://mapbox.com)  and google's Satellite view. But the cost of using the later is unclear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's licensing terms for the maps API is laid out [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing). There is a limitation on the number of map views, 25,000 according to this [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits), but that's quite large even in the free version. That page shows you the restrictions based on the two options::

- Google Maps API: "Your service must be freely and publicly accessible to end users."
- Google Maps API for Business: where you pay based on the type of application (OEM, asset tracking, location planning). Minimum pricing is $10,000 per year, but that could change (up or down). (I got the pricing information from a Google business rep. My company purchased the service.)

With the maps service they also provide:

Distance Matrix

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/05/what-is-distance-matrix.html

Directions Web Service

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/directions-web-service-arrives-at.html

Route Optimization

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/03/good-day-for-salesmen-that-travel-on.html

Styled Maps

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/add-touch-of-style-to-your-maps.html

Earth Plug-in

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2008/07/simulating-driving-directions-with.html

Reverse Geocoding

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2008/10/geocoding-in-reverse.html